# How to assign 'ng-style' directive value based on 'ng-repeat' count

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angularjs sample [snippet](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_tables_simple). here using ng-repeat directive to display names in a table, I am planning to add ng-style directive to add vertical scroll bar to a table based on table row count. how can i make below code to work?

Eg:  we need vertical scroll bar to a table only if the count of table rows is more than 4
I tried like this

```
<div ng-if= "names.length > 4" ng-style="{'overflow-y': 'auto'}" >
      <table>
        ---------
      </table>
</div>
```

Please help by correcting the code

Here is sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div> 
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle). It would likely be best to apply the (ng-)style to an element that contains the table. Set a *height* attribute (e.g. *100px*). Then the *overflow-y* style will cause any content beyond that threshold to be added in the scrolling area.

```
<div ng-style="containerStyle">
   <table>
    <!--table rows-->
   </table>
</div>
```

See this working the sample below.

**Note**: I changed the AJAX call to [an endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) from the [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), so as to avoid CORS issues.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.containerStyle = {
    border: '3px solid #f0f0f0',
    'max-height': '100px'
  };
  $http.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?key=U4DMV*8nvpm3EOpvf69Rxw((&site=stackoverflow&pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=default")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.names = response.data.items;
      if ($scope.names.length > 4) {
        $scope.containerStyle['overflow-y'] = 'auto'; // max-height: 30px;';
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

  <div ng-style="containerStyle">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.display_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.location }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, why are we hard-coding height of container? is it not possible with ng-if directive to check the ng-repeat count on fly?

Comment: I did that for to demonstrate the _overflow-y_ property... feel free to adjust it however you need.

Answer (score 0):

To choose which set of styles the table should use you can use a ternary operator to choose the set of styles.

```
<div ng-style="(names.length > 4 ? {'overflow-y': 'scroll'} : {'overflow-y': 'auto'})" 
     style="height: 50px;">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

I would suggest that if your styles get anymore complicated you should use the `ngClass` directive to apply a class if the condition is met and then define the styles you wish to apply in a stylesheet or `style` tag. This will make the code easier to read in my opinion.

```
<table ng-class="{'scrollable': names.length > 4}">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
    table { 
        overflow-y: auto;
        display: block;
    }
    .scrollable {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
<style>
```